# How to pass values to string array in post method using Fiddler?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, post, fiddler

When I'm passing the values in Fiddler like `{"rajehs","ramesh","ramsgkfhh"}`, I'm getting all the values in [0] location. I've also tried by using =  `{"rajehs","ramesh","ramsgkfhh"}`.

I declared the method like :

```
    public void Post([FromBody]string[] value)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a JSON object in our body, instead of an array. Use `[]` to pass a JSON array:

```
["rajehs","ramesh","ramsgkfhh"]
```

Comment: just now got it,,,,any way thanks for the fast response